# jQuery Mobile popup data-dismissible="false" problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

This is my first time using the jQUery Mobile popups. I've found documentation [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/#&ui-state=dialog) and [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/popup/). How I'm looking to create the following:

[image: This can be found in the second link]

Now according to the doc's, the following code should work:

```
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic" data-dismissible="false">
    <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.<p>
</div>
```

But given the code above I still keep getting the stock standard popup:

[image]

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`data-dismissible` means whether you want the popup to close once clicked outside it. The default value is `true`, if you set it to `false`, you have to add a button with `data-rel="back"` to close it, jQM wont add a close button dynamically/automatically.

Change your markup to the following.

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic" data-dismissible="false" data-theme="c" data-overlay-theme="a">
  <p>Click button to close this.</p>
  <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button">Close</a>
</div>
```

Note that `data-theme` and `data-overlay-theme` are different, the latter changes the color of the popup's overlay.

Or, you can close it programmatically.

```
$("#popupBasic").popup("close");
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/4mnp5/)**

Comment: Omar thank you for saving lives again! Any idea how I could fade the background out like in the picture I posted?

Comment: @Roberto you're welcome. This depends on `data-overlay-theme` added to the popup itself. I'll update the demo.